# How to change a dataframe including Date-time with daily resolution to half-hourly resolution

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, posixlt

I have a data.frame like

```
   WWH        V1        V2        V3        Names
  2018-01-01 0.3240454 0.4044979 0.6208009     a
  2018-01-01 0.7240454 0.6044979 0.9208009     b
  2018-01-01 0.6124702 0.9391351 0.1459288     c
  2018-01-02 0.5754003 0.9088237 0.7105769     a
  2018-01-02 0.6947945 0.1100394 0.4810563     b
  2018-01-02 0.3207489 0.4254129 0.1989616     c
```

in which the resolution of Date-time is daily. I need to change the resolution of Date-time to half hourly. So basically I need to repeat each row 48 times for which all the columns stay consistent except the first column that will get half hourly time values for the same date

```
  WWH                 V1        V2        V3        Names
  2018-01-01   00:00:00     0.3240454 0.4044979 0.6208009     a
  2018-01-01   00:30:00     0.3240454 0.4044979 0.6208009     a
  2018-01-01   01:00:00     0.3240454 0.4044979 0.6208009     a
```

.
.
.

```
  2018-01-02   21:30:00     0.3207489 0.4254129 0.1989616     c
  2018-01-02   22:00:00     0.3207489 0.4254129 0.1989616     c
  2018-01-02   22:30:00     0.3207489 0.4254129 0.1989616     c
  2018-01-02   23:00:00     0.3207489 0.4254129 0.1989616     c
  2018-01-02   23:30:00     0.3207489 0.4254129 0.1989616     c
```

here is reproducible code

```
WWH<-seq(as.POSIXlt("2018/1/1"), as.POSIXlt("2018/1/5"), "days")
Names<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
A1<- cbind("Date"=rep(WWH[1],5),as.data.frame(matrix(runif(15),5,3)),"Names"=Names)
A2<-cbind("Date"=rep(WWH[2],3),as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9),3,3)),"Names"=Names[1:3])
A3<-cbind("Date"=rep(WWH[3],2),as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2),2,3)),"Names"=Names[4:5])
df<-rbind(A1,A2,A3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using two steps with `rep()` and `seq()`.

Data:

```
WWH<-seq(as.POSIXlt("2018/1/1"), as.POSIXlt("2018/1/5"), "days")
Names<-c("a","e","r","c","u")
df <- cbind(WWH,as.data.frame(matrix(runif(15),5,3)),Names)
```

First we clone all rows of the dataframe 48 times to account for 48 half hours.

```
df.exp <- df[rep(row.names(df), each = 48), ]
```

Then we replace `WWH` by a sequence of half hours, beginning with the first day, ending at 23:30 of the last day:

```
df.exp$WWH <- seq(
  from=df$WWH[1],
  to=df$WWH[nrow(df)] + 84600,
  by=1800
)
```

Result:

```
> head(df.exp)
                    WWH       V1         V2        V3 Names
1   2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.639078 0.01123183 0.4661781     a
1.1 2018-01-01 00:30:00 0.639078 0.01123183 0.4661781     a
1.2 2018-01-01 01:00:00 0.639078 0.01123183 0.4661781     a
1.3 2018-01-01 01:30:00 0.639078 0.01123183 0.4661781     a
1.4 2018-01-01 02:00:00 0.639078 0.01123183 0.4661781     a
1.5 2018-01-01 02:30:00 0.639078 0.01123183 0.4661781     a

> tail(df.exp)
                     WWH        V1        V2        V3 Names
5.42 2018-01-05 21:00:00 0.1457907 0.5508916 0.7658603     u
5.43 2018-01-05 21:30:00 0.1457907 0.5508916 0.7658603     u
5.44 2018-01-05 22:00:00 0.1457907 0.5508916 0.7658603     u
5.45 2018-01-05 22:30:00 0.1457907 0.5508916 0.7658603     u
5.46 2018-01-05 23:00:00 0.1457907 0.5508916 0.7658603     u
5.47 2018-01-05 23:30:00 0.1457907 0.5508916 0.7658603     u
```

---

Bibliography:

[Replicate each row of data.frame and specify the number of replications for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894775/replicate-each-row-of-data-frame-and-specify-the-number-of-replications-for-each)

[Create a time series by 30 minute intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296749/create-a-time-series-by-30-minute-intervals)

[How to subtract/add days from/to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254986/how-to-subtract-add-days-from-to-a-date/39699347)

---

Edit: Here's a `dplyr` version using `interaction` to create a grouping variable:

```
WWH<-seq(as.POSIXlt("2018/1/1"), as.POSIXlt("2018/1/5"), "days")
Names<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
A1<- cbind("Date"=rep(WWH[1],5),as.data.frame(matrix(runif(15),5,3)),"Names"=Names)
A2<-cbind("Date"=rep(WWH[2],3),as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9),3,3)),"Names"=Names[1:3])
A3<-cbind("Date"=rep(WWH[3],2),as.data.frame(matrix(runif(2),2,3)),"Names"=Names[4:5])
df<-rbind(A1,A2,A3)

df.exp <- df[rep(row.names(df), each = 48), ]

  df.exp <- df.exp %>%
  mutate(temp = droplevels(interaction(df.exp$Date, df.exp$Names))) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  mutate(Datetime = seq(
    from = unique(Date),
    to = unique(Date) + 84600,
    by = 1800
  )) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-(temp))

tail(df.exp)

# A tibble: 6 x 6
        Date        V1        V2        V3  Names            Datetime
      <dttm>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <fctr>              <dttm>
1 2018-01-03 0.4327316 0.4327316 0.4327316      e 2018-01-03 21:00:00
2 2018-01-03 0.4327316 0.4327316 0.4327316      e 2018-01-03 21:30:00
3 2018-01-03 0.4327316 0.4327316 0.4327316      e 2018-01-03 22:00:00
4 2018-01-03 0.4327316 0.4327316 0.4327316      e 2018-01-03 22:30:00
5 2018-01-03 0.4327316 0.4327316 0.4327316      e 2018-01-03 23:00:00
6 2018-01-03 0.4327316 0.4327316 0.4327316      e 2018-01-03 23:30:00
```

Comment: the problem is that I have several rows with the same date. I edited the example to clarify.

Comment: `84600` is the amount of seconds in 23.5 hours.

Comment: @Nile I've edited in a new solution, see if it works for you.